# macOS Safari: how to quickly switch search engine

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

### TL;DR

I'm looking for a way to enable "search shortcuts" in macOS Safari. For example I want to be able to type `wi my search term` to search for "my search term" on Wikipedia, or `yt my search term` to search for "my search term" on YouTube. This is something that's built into Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome, but not in Safari.

### More info

I'm trying to give macOS Safari a honest try as my default browser. This with Safari 15.2, on macOS Monterey 12.1.

The major pain point for me is quick access to different search engines (or sites) in the address bar. I know I can choose the default from a short list (DuckDuckGo, Google, etc), and that I can also access extra search engines using "Enable Quick Website Search" in the preferences:

[image: screenshot of Safari preference panel to select search engines]

That's not great though, because if I want to search on Wikipedia, for example, I have to type the whole Wikipedia hostname before my search term, e.g. `en.wikipedia.org my search term`. Only then Safari will recognize it, and then I also have to press <kbd>↓</kbd> in order to actually select a Wikipedia search:

[image: screenshot of the macOS Safari address bar with a Wikipedia search]

That's a lot of keys to press, and slow.

Much slower, in fact, than what I'm used to with Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome, where I can configure the quick-search function to use keywords instead of the entire website hostname. For example, I can use `wi` for Wikipedia and `yt` for YouTube. It's just built into my muscle memory, I suppose.

I've looked for Safari extensions that would accomplish this, but couldn't find any. Any suggestion?

Comment: idk whether this really covers your use-case, but it's actually a bit smarter than that with defaults - type 'wiki [search]' or 'imdb [search]' etc & it gives you the option right underneath - https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZiFM.png it's aprt based on your habits & part on 'the obvious' so for instance - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ4VB.png 'apple computer' gives one 'obvious' & one here because I'm here a lot. Some you can abbreviate quite a lot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqcPC.png

Comment: Isin't thread name a bit misleading? This has nothing to do with quickly switching search engine. This is about searching specific sites.

Comment: Have you tried DuckDuckGo's 'bangs'? E.g. !w "my search term".